# Inner join statement in bind variables

Tags: c#, sql, bind-variables

I use bind variables to get data from the SQL tables.

The code:

```
string commandText = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} ORDER BY {3}", fields, from, whereStr, orderBy);
DbCommand command = GetSqlCommandWrapper(commandText);
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in whereParams)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(item, whereParamsBy[index++]));
}
DataTable db = new DataTable();

DataSet dataSet = null;
dataSet = CurrentDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(command);
```

The CommandText:

```
fields = "TableA.*";
from = "TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA .id = TableB.id";
whereStr = "TableA .id > 10";
orderBy = "TableA .id, TableB .id";
```

Everything works fine until I have to get data from 2 tables like the query:

```
select * from a inner join b on a.id = b.id where....
```

Someone can tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your `commandText` attempt that includes the inner join commands?

Comment: why and how does it fail? you'd include the joins in the `from` string or shift the `String.Format` arguments to the right, so {2} becomes your placeholder for the join clause(s). But IMO the whole approach is questionable. Could you use an existing framework for dynamic sql generation?

Comment: I inclieded it in the from string, but I get an error. can you give example how the commandText  shoud show?

Comment: Make your `from` contain `a inner join b on a.id = b.id`, done. You're generating the query text yourself, so it's your job to make sure the result ultimately makes sense. When constructing SQL, always evaluate the results afterwards (that is, print or inspect `commandText`); it's usually obvious when the syntax ends up wrong. Note that when you start doing joins, you want to add the table names to the `fields`, otherwise something like `id` is ambiguous.

Comment: I got this error: ORA-01036:Variable name or variable number is invalid

Comment: Undoubtedly -- and what's in `commandText` when it gives this error? What happens if you execute that query as a whole on the server? Does `whereParams` still match up with the statement's parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The overall approach is not very nice, but in terms of getting what you want, this should do it.

```
fields = "*";
from = "TableA AS a INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON a.id = b.id";
whereStr = "a.id > 10";
orderBy = "a.id, b.id";
```

Set your input parameters to that, or just paste it in before the code you gave us and it will produce the command `SELECT * FROM TableA AS a INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id > 10 ORDER BY a.id, b.id`

Please note that `orderBy = "a.id; DROP TABLE TableA;";` is a scary prospect